# why the DP solutions are so closely linked..?why the solution is just totally opposite?

Tags: dynamic-programming

The problem link is [Problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/AIBOHP/) . Although I am weak at DP I figured out a solution and got it acccepted but when I saw someone else's solution I was fascinated by  the closeness in the substructure...
My solution code

```
void solve()
{
char str[6102];
memset(dp,0,sizeof(dp));
scanf(" %s",str+1);
int i,j,k,l,n;
n=strlen(&str[1]);
for(l=2;l<=n;l++)
{
    for(i=1;i<=n-l+1;i++)
    {
        j=i+l-1;
        if(str[i]==str[j])
            dp[i][j]=dp[i+1][j-1];
        else
            dp[i][j]=min(dp[i+1][j]+1,dp[i][j-1]+1);
    }
}
printf("%d\n",dp[1][n]);
}
```

But when I saw the solution online it was simply 
answer=n - LCS( string, reversed string)

And now comparing the substructure the +1 side comes on the opposite side i.e.

```
recurse(i,j)=recurse(i+1,j-1) {If string[i]==string[j]}
 else
recurse(i,j)=min(recurse(i+1,j)+1,recurse(i,j-1)+1);
```

for my code and for LCS is here [geeksforgeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-4-longest-common-subsequence/)(I think you obviously know this).. But I do not know why the solution is just totally opposite... in place of max--> min ... and that +1 part too(Comes with recurse(i,j-1)+1)..

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why are they so closely related ? And how can we derive one from the other